# Netbeans 8.2 not making Java EE application

Tags: jakarta-ee, netbeans

I have Java 1.8, and Netbeans 8.2 installed. I want to make EE applications. But when I do new project-> Java EE(Is not to be found) 
 Do I need to change the IDE version?

Answer (score 0):

Netbeans 8.2 came along in different flavours (https://netbeans.org/downloads/8.2/). If you haven't installed the "Java EE" or "All" edition you could install the missing plugins via the plugin center.